# Creating Dynamic ID and checking ID in jquery and php

Tags: jquery

```
$('#commentAlink').click(function()
     {   $('div').click(function()
         {   var ID=this.id;
             if(ID).click(function(){     $('#divcommenttextbox').show(); });                });   });
<?php   while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { $topicid=$rows['TopicID'];
       echo $rows['Title_of_Topic'];
?>
<div class="commentlink" id="<?php echo $topicid; ?>"><a href="#" id="commentAlink">Comment</a></div>
<div id="divcommenttextbox"><textarea name="topiccomment" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br />
    <a href="#" class="commentlink" id="cancellink">Cancel</a> <input type="button" value="Comment" />
</div> <?php } ?>
```

here is my problem i got all the Id' from my database and show record
I like to show comment link and if comment click, I need to show div tag.
I can do only for first record. please tell me what wrong am i doing
hope u understand my problem. waiting for the reply

Comment: Please format your code and try to formulate a short question in natural language on what your problem is.

Comment: Your Code doesn't make sense, and I don't know what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, is this what you're trying to do:

**jQuery**

```
$('.commentAlink').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#divcommenttextbox_'+id).show();
});
$('.cancellink').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#divcommenttextbox_'+id).hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $topicid=$rows['TopicID'];
        echo $rows['Title_of_Topic'];
?>
    <div class="commentlink" id="<?php echo $topicid; ?>">
        <a href="#" rel="<?php echo $topicid; ?>" class="commentAlink">Comment</a>
    </div>
    <div id="divcommenttextbox_<?php echo $topicid; ?>">
        <textarea name="topiccomment" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br />
        <a href="#" class="commentlink cancellink">Cancel</a>
        <input type="button" value="Comment" />
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I changed some of your IDs to Classes because you can't have two ids that are the same on one page.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, I can't hide div tag. What I want to do is after comment click, div tag will be display and cancel click dive will be hide. Every record has comment link.

Comment: To hide it, I add class in div tag
 <div class="divcommenttextbox" id="divcommenttextbox_<?php echo $topicid; ?>">

Comment: It's so wonderful. I could show and hide in each record. Thanks Emmanuel. You show me how to use two class in one link.  Here is code
 <div  class="divcommenttextbox" id="divcommenttextbox_<?php echo $topicid; ?>">       
   <textarea name="topiccomment" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br />        
    <a href="#" class="commentlink cancellink" rel="<?php echo $topicid; ?>">Cancel</a>       
      <input type="button" value="Comment" />     
  </div>

Comment: What you want to do is hide the divcommenttextbox and only show it when the link is clicked. Yes you're on the right track with the class. So just add this to the beginning of your jQuery `$('.divcommenttextbox').hide();`

Comment: That's good idea. but I write in css.so, I have to give the class name.